# Firebase how to block specific node in DB

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that gets updated each time something is changed in firebase database.
In my database, I have "posts" node and some children inside such as "likes", "comments" and so on.

My loadRecyclerView function :

```
    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (posts.size() > 0) {
                posts.clear();
            }

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Post post = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                //Getting a specific user's information (nickname purposes)
                    posts.add(0, post);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

My code works and everything gets updated on every change in Firebase, but I would like to keep the listener on everything EXCEPT new post (I made a scroll up to refresh for that).
Any ideas ??

Comment: where are you updating, the method above is for retrieving

Comment: @PeterHaddad correct me if im wrong, but the notifyDataSetChanged is calling the adapter each time data is changed in FB DB

Comment: "I would like to keep the listener on everything EXCEPT new post" I don't really understand what you mean by this. Can you rephrase it in other words?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure. I want that every change in data base will result with a change inside the app, except new post which will take place in the next refresh

Comment: Aha, that will require a listener that ends at the latest post. So something like `databaseReference.orderByKey().endAt("key of newest post").addValueEventListener(`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting only posts before now will require a listener that ends at the latest post. So something like

```
databaseReference.orderByKey().endAt("key of newest post").addValueEventListener(...
```

To determine the key of the newest post, you can attach a listener for just the latest value:

```
databaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(...
```

So combined:

```
databaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String lastKey;

    for (String child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      lastKey = child.getKey();
    }

    databaseReference.orderByKey().endAt(lastKey).addValueEventListener((new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (posts.size() > 0) {
            posts.clear();
        }

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Post post = ds.getValue(Post.class);
            //Getting a specific user's information (nickname purposes)
                posts.add(0, post);

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSet...
```